# Passing refs to an array of children to call child methods (useRef / useImperativeHandle)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This question is about *useRef* and *useImperativeHandle* hooks.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle

Is there a way to use useRef on an array of items? I’d like to render a number of child components, passing a different ref to each one.

```js
const Parent = ({items: string[]}) => {
    const numberOfItems = items.length;
    const refs = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i ++) {
        const ref = useRef(null);
        refs.push(ref);
    }

    return items.map((item, index) => <Child ref={ref[i]} text={item} />);
}
```

The reason I'd need this is to call the method in each Child (returning a serialized state).

This is the code in Child:

```js
const serialize = () => JSON.stringify(someState);

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    serialize,
}));
```

This works for a single component (and not an array of). From parent, I could call the ref.current.serialize(), which runs the method in Child.

However, it doesn't work for array (due to different number of hooks getting called):

[image: Error message]

I understand that this is not the "React way of doing things" and that you'd probably suggest to keep my state (to serialize) in top component. However, due to some other benefits, I'm wondering if this is somehow doable? I.e. could the effort you've put into the *useImperativeHandle* hook work (great thing btw) could somehow be extended to an array of children?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the intended usage of `useImperativeHandle`. This hook is usually only used in situations where you need to access tricky DOM properties/methods like focusing or scrolling, which are hard to access otherwise. In your case, you are not doing anything with the DOM, so you definitely do not need to use this kind of very advanced hooks.

Also, using hooks in a loop is not just "not the React way", it will definitely break if the number of items ever changes (and there is no way to fix it without fundamentally changing how hooks work).

Instead you could try to pass a callback from the parent to the child, that the child will then call with the serialized string, but it’s hard to give an example without knowing what you are trying to do with the `refs` variable in the parent.

Comment: Thanks!

Yes, I could do that (provide a callback), but then I’d also need a way to “trigger” the component to call the callback.

To illustrate the problem: imagine a tree control where each child maintains the info of its child nodes in its local state (and not in the central place as a complete tree structure).

At one point the user would “copy” the node by clicking is, and in this moment the whole sub-structure (descendants) should deserialize (recursivelly, like “walking the DOM).

Comment: You can trigger the callback in various places, for instance in event listeners or in a useEffect